# Add Existing Tag/Segment To Contacts

Tags: node.js, tags, mailchimp-api-v3

Lately I have found [mailchimp-api-v3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailchimp-api-v3) to be quite useful for managing our .1k list. Currently, I use the following to (1) create **new tags**, and (2) **add the tag to contacts**:

```
const MC = require('mailchimp-api-v3');
const mailchimp = new MC('<apiKey>');

mailchimp.batch([{
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/lists/<list_id>/segments',
    body: {
        name: '<tag1>',
        static_segment: [<contact_list1>]
    }
}, {
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/lists/<list_id>/segments',
    body: {
        name: '<tag2>',
        static_segment: [<contact_list2>]
    }
}])
.then(results => {
    console.log( results );
})
.catch(errs => {
    console.log( errs );
});
```

Sometimes there's need to add an **existing tag** to contacts. Whenever I try to use the above code, as expected, I get *tag already exists* error and **contacts are not tagged** with this **existing tag.**

How do I get a list of all existing tags? And how would one add an existing tag to contacts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to do that. The just updated documentation is much easier to navigate that before. It's now evident that there are two ways of adding a tag/segment to (a) member(s): you can add a single tag to a member or you can add a single tag to many members:

**Bulk add with `members_to_add`:** array

```
{
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/lists/{list_id}/segments/{segment_id}',
    body: {members_to_add: [<email-addresses>]}
}
```

This is indeed what I needed and I have now been using it for a while. Just today I found out the other method:

**Single add with `email_address`:** string

```
{
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/lists/{list_id}/segments/{segment_id}/members',
    email_address: {email_address}
}
```